# Relation between eigenvalues of $AB$ and $A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The following question is almost the converse of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492746/eigenvalues-of-ab-from-eigenvalues-of-a-and-b) question.

Let $A$ and $B$, $A \neq B$, be two $2$ by $2$ matrices over a field of characteristic zero.
Assume that one of the eigenvalues of $AB$ (and hence also of $BA$) is $1$.

> What can be said about the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$?

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: Almost nothing can be said, except that the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are nonzero when $AB$ is nonsingular, or at least one of $A,B$ has a zero eigenvalue when $AB$ is singular. Consider the case where $A$ is a nonsingular complex matrix and $B=A^{-1}$. All nonzero complex numbers are possible eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @user1551, thank you! I liked the example with $B=A^{-1}$. What about the eigenvectors of $A$, $B$ and $AB$? Any relation between them?

Comment: I haven't any nice illustrative examples at hand, but in general, the eigenvectors or eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ have very little to do with the eigenstructure of $AB$. Conjugation (i.e. $X\mapsto PXP^{-1}$) preserves eigenstructure, but the mere multiplication of $A$ and $B$ does not preserve the eigenstructure of any one of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @user1551, thank you! So only when $A=B$ more can be said, like in the following question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241764/eigenvalues-and-power-of-a-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: There are other nice scenarios. When $A$ and $B$ commute and the underlying field is algebraically closed, the two matrices can be simultaneously triangularised. In this case, $A,B$ and $AB$ share at least one eigenvector and every eigenvalue of $AB$ is a product of an eigenvalue from $A$ and an eigenvalue from $B$. If both $A$ and $B$ are diagonalisable, $A,B$ and $AB$ share even an eigenbasis.

Comment: Thank you very much!